# Damaged GRUB 2 in my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I have a genuine Windows 8 pre-installed on my laptop. I installed the Ubuntu in UEFI mode, using a live CD, but now the GRUB doesn't show, hence,not allowing me to boot to windows if I want to. It directly boots to Ubuntu.

Now, I googled this problem, and I found out this [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

What I don't understand is, the link says to follow the instructions after running the terminal from the LIVE CD or so, but how can I run it when I don't have the GRUB, I mean, it wont even recognize that DVD.
Please help, I need the windows too, and I don't want to go to the service center.

PS: After installation, Ubuntu asked for software updates, and so I did, and also at the software and updates section, I selected the proprietary driver for my AMD graphics card. Since I didn't restart in between, I cannot tell whether the problem is caused by them or not.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? so do the same instruction but instead of selecting Install Ubuntu choice "Try with Ubuntu", this option gives you to boot from Ubuntu live cd then open the terminal with hot keys (Ctrl+Alt+T) and follow instructions in above link.

Answer (score 1):

First I have to say before loading Ubuntu Grub the computer need to know what device has the highest priority to boot. Usually this is the internal hard disk with the Ubuntu Grub, but you can change the device priority and set the CD to be the first device to boot so you'll boot from CD.

To boot from a LIVE CD  or LIVE USB, you have 2 options:

1. Enter BIOS
2. Use Boot Menu pressing F12

---

**Enter The BIOS**

The most generic way is the first one, to access the BIOS of your PC pressing DEL/ESC when PC is starting, you can follow this small tutorial: [How to enter your BIOS](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241032/how_to_enter_your_pcs_bios.html)

Once you're in the BIOS you have to change in the BOOT tab the Boot Device Priority and set your CD/DVD the first one, save and restart.

You have another small tutorial about changing device priority here: [Change Boot Order Tutorial](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm)

Once you succesfully changed the priority, your PC should boot from CD and you'll see the Menu that says "Try Ubuntu..."

---

**Use Boot Menu**

If your BIOS has this option, when the computer is starting, at the same time you can read in the bottom of the screen "Press DEL to enter SETUP" yo'll see "Press F12 to BOOT Menu".

If you Press F12 then it'll appear a Menu where you can select wich device boot from, so you should choose your CD/DVD drive or USB, and when the computer boot from the chosen drive, do the same as before, select "Try Ubuntu..."

This second way is easier because you avoid entering the BIOS but not all the computers has this option